# How to convert DWORD to string in Python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am working on a C++ SDK using Python. One of the APIs looks like this

**API**

```
DWORD NET_DVR_GetSDKVersion(
);
```

**Documentation**

> 2 higher bytes mean the major version, 2 lower bytes mean the minor version, e.g. 0x00030000 means version 3.0.

It returns a `DWORD` value. I did some research and it seems like `DWORD` equals to `ctypes.c_ulong` in Python.

However, all I get from the API is an integer `393216` that does not make much sense.

**Code**

```
sdk = cdll.LoadLibrary("sdk.so")
sdk.NET_DVR_GetSDKVersion.restype = ctypes.c_long
result = sdk.NET_DVR_GetSDKVersion()
```

I have setting the return value type using `c_char_p` and several other types but results don't really make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2 higher bytes mean the major version, 2 lower bytes mean the minor version, e.g. 0x00030000 means version 3.0.

As you can see in the example, the number is in the hex format (0x prefix). In hex format you can easily see the bytes - 2 hex digits=1 byte (because 16*16 is 256).

You need to convert your number to hex using `hex(your_value_here)` and cut it into 2 parts for major and minor version.

In your case `hex(393216)` returns `'0x60000'` - that is `0x0` as 2 lower bytes (minor version) and `0x6` as higher bytes (major version), giving version 6.0

EDIT:

You can also extract your version using binary operations. Use `your_number_here>>16` to move your number 16 bits (2 bytes) right, i.e. removing the lower 2.

So it's `your_number>>16` for major, `your_number - (your_number>>16<<16)` for minor.

Answer (score 2):

Post process your number to extract the upper and lower 16 bits and format them as a string.  Below are examples using Python 3.6+ f-strings:

```
>>> dword = 393216
>>> hex(dword)
'0x60000'
>>> f'{dword>>16}.{dword&0xFFFF}'
'6.0'
>>> dword = 0x00020003
>>> f'{dword>>16}.{dword&0xFFFF}'
'2.3'
```